# mysql 5.7.9 : windows log: Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm using the mysql 5.7.9-log on windows2012 as service.
Then connect and query  to the mysql with .netconnector or phpmysqli 
Got every query this information on windows event :

> Aborted connection 2481 to db: 'dbdb' user: 'myuser' host: '127.0.0.1'
>   (Got an error reading communication packets)...

but query successfully applied 
don't happened on mysql5.6

my my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
port= 3306
basedir = "C:/KAPPS/mysql/" 
tmpdir = "C:/KAPPS/mysql/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/KAPPS/mysql/data"
plugin_dir = "C:/KAPPS/mysql/lib/plugin/" 
server-id   = 1
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
#bind-address=0.0.0.0 # I tried

# custom config
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
event_scheduler=ON
wait_timeout=10000
max_allowed_packet = 10M
skip_name_resolve
group_concat_max_len=15360
slow_query_log=ON
slow_query_log_file="slow_queries.log"

# performance
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M 
join_buffer_size = 256M
query_cache_size = 256M
key_buffer_size=512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G 
sql_mode=
```

Any suggestion ?

edit:

this my.ini line solved my problem:

log_error_verbosity=1

ref [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) link

Comment: Does the query take a long time to run?

Comment: no same as mysql 5.6 : 200-300 ms